Responding to possible collusion
I was playing at a 1-3 NLH game at a casino in Colorado. I was seated in the 8 spot and the 6 and 7 spot were taken by what I later learned to be a father and son with the father next to me in the 7 spot. I noticed that they were showing each other cards during hands when the other had folded. I had no issue with this as I do that at times as well.
During the hand in question the son and I had folded while the father considered a large ($40) bet pre-flop while showing his hand to his son. The son clearly whispered 'Push it' to his father who then raised $100. I immediately walked over to the floor manager and described what happened and he told me they were father and son. He went and had a talk with the son but did not separate them. I thought this was too much of a possibility for collusion and left.
I have seen the 'one player per hand' guideline to keep people from offering advice but not sure if this is an actual rule. What is your experience with this situation and should the floor manager have separated them?

I stopped playing poker in casinos long ago.  It's simply too easy for players to cheat, and the house often does nothing about it.
Sometimes the dealers or pit bosses look the other way because they are receiving large "tips" (kickbacks) from the cheaters; sometimes they look the other way because it is less work for them.  Sometimes they have other reasons.
The last time I played in a casino, a member of law enforcement and his wife were playing at the same table.  It was incredibly obvious to everyone that they were cheating.  The hand signals were blatant.  One by one, people left the table with disgust as the house refused to take any action.
Yes, in your case, the house should have separated the colluding players.  But as you experienced, they chose not to take any real action.  Sadly, not a big surprise.

Your first paragraph is kind of odd, since, it's much easier to collude online than it is in person.

@TTT Oh, I agree.  I never would consider playing online for significant money due to that fact.  Online could actually potentially be designed to be more resistant to collusion than in-person because there are ways the house could make it almost impossible for humans to collude, but I've never actually seen those steps taken.  And, if they were taken, IMO, it would make the game less fun, which is perhaps one reason why those steps haven't been taken.

@TTT BTW, I only mentioned casinos because the question was about casinos, not online.

Ah OK. I was assuming if you aren't playing in casinos anymore, then you are playing online. But I guess you mean you only play in private games now? ;)
